# Re-ordering data in table excluding rows with blank cells in certain columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of "Tasks" stored in a table with the parts needed to perform the task stored in the columns. I want extract the tasks that require parts and re-order the as shown in the "Parts Required" table. Is this possible to do without the use of scripts?

```
Tasks
+-----------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|      Task       |  Part 1  | Quantity 1 |   Part 2   | Quantity 2 |
+-----------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| Oil Change      | Oil      |         10 | Oil Filter |          1 |
| Clean Engine    |          |            |            |            |
| Impeller Change | Impeller |          1 |            |            |
+-----------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+

Parts Required
+-----------------+------------+----------+
|      Task       |    Part    | Quantity |
+-----------------+------------+----------+
| Oil Change      | Oil        |       10 |
| Oil Change      | Oil Filter |        1 |
| Impeller Change | Impeller   |        1 |
+-----------------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:C, ROW(A1:A); A2:A, D2:E, ROW(A2:A)}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col2 is not null", 1))
```

[image]